# Datatable custom error handling not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am writing an application using Data-table plugin. I want to handle the error thrown by plugin by my function but plugin always show a alert box with error message.

In the page load event, I am creating a datatable plugin and registering a handler.

```
function callOnLoad()
{
    $.fn.dataTable.ext.errorMode = "none";

    auditViewTable = $("#div").on("error.dt",function(e, settings, techNote, message ){
        console.log("error");
    })
    .DataTable({
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "ajax": "getData",
        "columns": [
            { "data": "events" },
            { "data": "id" },
            { "data": "name" },
            { "data": "obj_id" },
            { "data": "obj" }
        ]
    });
}
```

Please help me where I am going wrong.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

See the documentation -> **http://datatables.net/reference/event/error**

1. `error.dt` was first introduced in **1.10.5** !! So you must use at least 1.10.5. Proof of concept : [**works not, 1.10.4 example**](http://jsfiddle.net/xjqacedc/) / [**works, 1.10.5 example**](http://jsfiddle.net/6L9uc6t6/).
2. The correct option to target is `$.fn.dataTable.ext.errMode`.
3. A working example would be using >1.10.4 and

```js
$.fn.dataTable.ext.errMode = 'none';
$('#example').on('error.dt', function(e, settings, techNote, message) {
   console.log( 'An error has been reported by DataTables: ', message);
})
```

Comment: For me `error` event is not firing and version using is **1.10.12**.
I set error mode with 'none'

`Backbone.$.fn.dataTable.ext.errMode = 'none';`

Binding `error`  event as below:

`var table = this.ui.table.DataTable(dataTablesOptions)
.on('error', function () {

})`